# a question on Frechet derivative

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose the derivative of a functional is given by $\int_{\Omega}(\vec{v}.\nabla u)|\nabla u|^{p-2} \phi$ for $\phi\in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$, then what is the functional?.

Comment: The functional acts on $u$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't fully specify. So the functional acts on $u$, the derivative is taken at a point $u$. Is $v$ the variation (i.e. the argument of the derivative), or is it $\phi$?

Comment: $\vec{v}$ is a known vector and is a function of $x$.

Comment: @Ian...yes as u rightly said that the derivative is to be computed at $u$ and $\phi$ is the argument of the derivative. $\vec{v}$ is a known vector field.

Comment: @Ian...In the above asked question you may also consider $\nabla. u\vec{v}= \vec{v}.\nabla u$ by assuming that the vector field $\vec{v}$ is irrotational, i.e., $\nabla.\vec{v}=0$. So, $\int_{\Omega}(\vec{v}.\nabla u)|\nabla u|^{p-2} \phi=\int_{\Omega}\nabla. (u\vec{v})|\nabla u|^{p-2}\phi$.